# How display all methods from an object from twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

I tried to get a list of all methods with twig dump.

```
<div>
    {% if listPosts is defined %}
        {{ dump(listPosts) }}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

But I only get this list:

```
SlidingPagination {#575 ▼

  -route: "bissap_forum_topic"
  -params: array:2 [▶]
  -pageRange: 2
  -template: "KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sliding_bissap.html.twig"
  -sortableTemplate: "KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig"
  -filtrationTemplate: "KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:filtration.html.twig"
  #currentPageNumber: "1"
  #numItemsPerPage: 8
  #items: array:8 [▶]
  #totalCount: 11
  #paginatorOptions: array:6 [▶]
  #customParameters: []
}
```

How can I display all the methods names of an object inside twig?

Comment: So you want to get a list of all "methods"/"functions" an object has ? Private and/or public ? Or do you just want to call a objects method?
Please be clearer with what you want!

Comment: I wanted to get "numItemsPerPage", I know i can with `getItemNumberPerPage`, I found this with search google, but it will be  easier if i can display all methods/functions private or public...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a [twig filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters). This way you could implement an e.g. `list_functions` filter in php an use it from twig like:

```
{{ listPosts | list_functions }}
```

You need to implement the logic in php as you cannot use php in twig directly. It should be easy using [get_class_methode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php). This way you get a list of all function, but you then have to decide which function you want to call.